# How did the program worked??

Tags: c

the for loop should be infinite as I have assigned NULL '\0' to it.. but it acts normally..

```
/* a program to copy string str1 to str2 without using string handling function*/
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str1[50],str2[50],ch;
    int i;
    printf("Enter String1:");
    gets(str1);
    for(i=0; str1[i]>='\0'; i++)
    {
        str2[i]=str1[i];
    }
    printf("String1 : %s\nString2 : %s\n", str1, str2);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: other than the potential overflow, and the fact that `!=` would be better than `>=`, this code looks OK to me. Why do you expect it to fail?

Comment: Please submit formatted questions, with expected output.

Comment: `char` is signed.  When you walk off the end of the string, you are likely to encounter a byte with the msb set, which will cause the loop to terminate.

Comment: `char` may be signed in C, so it's possible you entered a character with a negative value.

Comment: any example of signed char??

Comment: `char` being signed seems to be the default for compilers targeting x86-series CPUs. Your compiler should have a switch you can use to set `char` to be unsigned, if you want to test that out.

Answer (score 0):

This check: str1[i]>='\0' is a signed comparison.  Once you access uninitialized data past the boundary of str1 you will eventually access a byte with a value > 127, which is negative when used in a signed comparison and therefore less than zero ('\0'), so the loop terminates.  It's also possible that the program could encounter an access violation and crash before it encounters a negative byte - it just depends on what's in memory, but your program will be trashing memory that lies after str2, if it doesn't crash.

This code is unsafe and an example of how buffer overflows happen.  The correct check for terminating the loop is "str1[I] != '\0'".

Comment: when I used "str1[i] != '\0'", I had to add "str2[i]='\0';" after the for loop.. why is that??

Comment: You need to null-terminate the destination string.